# TinyMCE > Make style_formats work as a radio list instead of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to add a custom style to the TinyMCE formats menu item

I have added an item, with submenu items. Problem is that these submenu items work as a checkbox, and not as a radio list.

I want to be able to only have one of the classes applied to the element, so if it currently has "Id 1" applied to the element, and the user wishes to switch to "Id 2". I want to remove the "id1" class and then add the "id2" class.

Can this be done?

Currently I have this

```
style_formats: [
      {title: 'Indent', items: [
        {title: 'Id 1', selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', classes: 'id1'},
        {title: 'Id 2', selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', classes: 'id2'},
        {title: 'Id 3', selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', classes: 'id3'}
      ]}
    ]
```